# See value textBox3(from tabPage1) in textBox4(from tabPage2)

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am beginner in Visual Basic and C#. Have this situation in C#. 3 textBox in tabPage1 (textBox1+textBo2=textBox3) and textBox4 in tabPage2. I want show value from TextBox3 (from TabPage1) in TextBox4 (TabPage2).  Value from textBox3 = textBox4. Please a code in VB and/or C#. Thanks !!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIgPG.jpg)

Comment: You need to pick one or the other. Correct your tags.

Comment: `textBox1+textBo2=textBox3` You cannot add a TextBox to another TextBox. You can't even do addition with the Text property. `textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text ` Suppose textBox1 contains 12 and textBox2 contains 34. The plus sign would concatenate the strings and you would get 1234. You need to convert the String in the .Text property to a number type if you want do addition. In vb.net `CInt(textBox1.Text)`

Comment: Hello.  TK for the reply. It is possible. After you make 3 textBox (textBox1, textBox2,textBox3) in textBox2 put THE CODE :                                                        if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text)))
            {
textBox3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) +Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)).ToString();                                                               Maybe you find a solution for my question. Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `Integer.TryParse` you don't have to check for an empty text box. It will check for a valid number and fill the second parameter with the converted value. What you want to remember is the `.Text` properties are `String` and you need numbers to do addition. Otherwise, your strings will be concatenated.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim t1 As Integer
    Dim t2 As Integer
    Dim total As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, t1) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, t2) Then
        total = t1 + t2
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number in each text box.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Form2.Show()
    Form2.TextBox4.Text = total.ToString
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
OK, you still need some event to trigger the action.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim t1 As Integer
    Dim t2 As Integer
    Dim total As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox7.Text, t1) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(TextBox8.Text, t2) Then
        total = t1 + t2
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number in each text box.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    TextBox9.Text = total.ToString
    TextBox10.Text = total.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I forgot to specify without Button. I tried to post an image with Form1 and tabPage1 and tabPage2 but I can't. Can you please write to me at foxinthebox67@gmail.com. You would help me a lot.

Comment: There are other events you could use.. I would like to help as much as I can but Stack Overflow not only benefits the one who asks the question but all users. Any help given is for the benefit of all. We cannot do private tutoring.

Comment: Partly it's OK. Only I don't have Form1 and Form2 but TabPage1 and TabPage2 :) Here's the problem. TK for yours code.

Comment: You clearly do have a Form1. This code is tested and works. TextBoxes 7, 8 and 9 are on TabPage1 and TextBox10 is on TabPage2.